# get partial data after regex match to substitute in original string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to replace part of a string using `re.sub`. With a static replacement string, I can do:

```
>>> data = "{'user': <User: some name>, 'user': <User: n0n@m3>}"
>>> test = re.sub(r'\<[^>]*\>', "'something'", data)
>>> test
"{'user': 'something', 'user': 'something'}"
```

However, I am looking to get the end result

```
>>> test
"{'user': 'some name', 'user': 'n0n@m3'}"
```

wherein the replacement string is part of the originally substituted string. How can I do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

```
>>> data = "{'user': <User: some name>, 'user': <User: n0n@m3>}"
>>> re.sub(r'<[^:>]*:\s*([^>]*)>', r"'\1'", data)
"{'user': 'some name', 'user': 'n0n@m3'}"
```

**Explanation:**

- `<` matches a literal `<` symbol. Since it wasn't a regex meta charcaterm you don't need to escape it in-order to match a literal `<` symbol.
- `[^:>]*` matches any character but not of a colon or `>`, zero or more times.
- `:\s*` matches a colon and the following zero or more spaces.
- `([^>]*)` Now this captures all the remaining characters upto `>` symbol.
- By replacing all the matched characters, ie the whole `<..>` block with thw chars present inside group index 1 surrounded by single quotes will give you the desired output.